# Formidable Pro - SELECT from database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, forms, formidable

I want to create a form with Formidable. I just have a question (I don't have the pro version, so no official support. This is why I post my question here) :

Is it possible to get data from a database, in order to fill a select ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is a field type called 'Dynamic Field', which will let you select a field from another form and it will populate the dropdown options with the values entered in that field. So if you add a dynamic field to Form A point it at a field in Form B, every time someone adds an entry to Form B the value for that field will be available as a drop-down option in Form A.

However, I think dynamic fields are only available in Formidable Pro.